# Is there a good way to tell that a string isn't undefined, null and '' in angular template?

Tags: angular

Is there a good way to tell that a string isn't `undefined`, `null` and `''` in angular template?
If the value is valid, then dispaly this part.

```
<div class="flex-row date-area" *ngIf="startDate !== undefined && startDate !== null && startDate !== ''">
    <label class="date-label">start date</label>
    <label class="date-content">{{startDate | dateFormat:'ymd'}}</label>
</div>
```

Apparently, I can place the logic in a method of the component class, like:

```
<div class="flex-row date-area" *ngIf="isValid(startDate)">
    <label class="date-label">start date</label>
    <label class="date-content">{{startDate | dateFormat:'ymd'}}</label>
</div>
```

I'm wondering if there's a better way to handle this, especially when I have to handle many logics like this.

Answer (score 2):

undefined, null and '' all evaluate to "falsey" values so you could just do `*ngIf="startDate"` and the code should work the same as you laid it out in your first example.

Also I don't see an issue with your second example. What is the problem you're encountering?